# on webkit browsers typing into edit box causes scrolling

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari, webkit

I have an issue with website markup on WebKit browsers (Chrome & Safari), i.e. when I type something in edit box of right-slider, it scrolls the left area.

Please take a look at following example:
http://jsbin.com/obiyec/7 
http://jsbin.com/obiyec/7/edit - html code (input is inside div with id="palette")

1. Open next link in Chrome or Safari
2. Type something in edit box in right upper corner
3. Notice that scrollbar in left area shifts

*It is very unlikely to change this markup radically if possible*

Q. How to prevent scroll-bar from shifting and make it behave same way as it is in FF?

Comment: Your problem description is unclear.  There's no "edit box" in your example, it's just a static `div`.  Maybe you want a `textarea`?

Comment: @Sparky672 try the links. If you open the [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/obiyec/7) in Chrome, there is an input field in the top right corner. Type in it and the `div` on the left with an `overflow: auto` will scroll to the right even though it is not being interacted with.

Comment: @MyHeadHurts, I'm in Safari and I cannot type anything into the top left box.  Looking at the HTML, it's just a `div`.

Comment: @Sparky672 sorry, that was me being an idiot. I meant top right input box (I've also corrected the comment).

Comment: @MyHeadHurts, I tried that too.  Entering text in top-right box (and hitting return/enter) does nothing in Safari.

Comment: @Sparky672 you need to type some text into it, not just hit return

Comment: @MyHeadHurts, I thought I said that already ~  _"**Entering text** in top-right box (and hitting return/enter) does nothing..."_

Comment: @Sparky672 I tried in both browses, but on Win 7 machine, probably it does matter.

Comment: I don't totally understand what your asking but you can remove a lot of these kind of problems by using a "reset css" at the start of your stylesheet to reset all the different browser default css to a base setting. http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: @Sparky672 I'm on Win 7 and get the behaviour in both browsers

Comment: For whatever it's worth, I'm in Safari 5 Mac.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. Changed the description, hope this will clarify it.

Comment: Maybe I'm looking in the wrong place, but I'm not finding any documentation on `input type="edit"`. http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/inputs.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is that what it looks like you are doing and what you are actually doing are two different things.

It looks like the `div` on the left with a fixed width and `overflow: auto` (`div#kb-board`) and the input field on the right are unrelated elements - but they are not. The input field is actually a child of `div#kb-board` but its parent (`div#palette`) has `fixed` positioning so it sits in the top right of the page.

As a result, the input field is actually on the right hand side of `div#kb-board` and when you type in it the scroll bar moves as you are giving focus to the right hand side of that div.

So in this case, I would say Chrome is showing the correct behavior.

To resolve this you should stop nesting `div#palette` within `div#kb-board`. Since it uses fixed positioning, there is no need to nest it.

```
<div id="kb-board">
    <div id="boards-container">
        <div id="lane">...</div>
    </div>
    <!-- div#palette was originally here -->
</div>
<div id="palette">
    <input type="text" value="Type here" />
</div>
```

**Working example: http://jsbin.com/obiyec/8**

Comment: You are right. I suspected that FF might ignore the need of focusing div's rather than WebKit. Nice catch. Thanks!

Comment: Can anyone point me to the documentation for `input type="edit"`?  Thank-you.

Comment: @Sparky672 Sorry, I definitely meant input type="text" . Here it is: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#text-type-text-state-and-search-state-type-search

Comment: We are using a framework where we have no handle of html divs and so on. The layout is created on a more abstract level. But based on your answer we saw that the same issue would be solved merely by simplifying our layout. So simplification works! Thanks for the hint